# uses-feature: is the sum of all subfeatures always identical to the parent feature?

Tags: android, android-manifest, uses-feature

Some features are broken down into subfeatures, such as the telephony feature:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony.gsm" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony.cdma" android:required="false" />
```

Now the question is: if setting all subfeatures to not be required, can it still make sense to require the parent feature, based on the assumption that there is functionality covered by the parent feature that goes beyond the sum of all subfeatures?

Comment: Not that this really answers your question, but one reason to require *only* the parent feature that I just discovered is that the apps *requiring* ".gsm" are (for no discernible reason) not visible in the Android Market on 1.6 devices.

Comment: interesting, thanks for sharing